# Cron job running cmd when it should not

Tags: cron

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
```

Cron tab line:

```
38 13 15-21 * 2 /usr/bin/wall "3rd Tuesday of the month?"
```

So what I expect is that wall program will write to every logged in user and tell the message. I want this to happen every 3rd tuesday of the month,each month.

According to cron.guru the explanation is: *At 13:38 on every day-of-month from 15 through 21 and on Tuesday.*

So why did it run today 6th october 2020? it would appear that the filter for the days of the week is not working being that today is the 6th of the month and the filter should only pass on the 15 throught to the 21st. Does this work for anyone else? is it a bug? where should it be reported?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem, 15-21 is the 3rd week of the month and you would have gotten the 3rd Tuesday instead of the 2nd if cron was working the way you expected.

Answer (score 1):

That is the documented behavior. Specifically, from `man 5 crontab`:

> ```
>    Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields —
>    day of month, and day of week.  If both fields  are  restricted  (i.e.,
>    aren't  *),  the command will be run when either field matches the cur‐
>    rent time.  For example,
>    ``30 4 1,15 * 5'' would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st
>    and  15th  of  each month, plus every Friday. One can, however, achieve
>    the desired result by adding a test to the command (see the last  exam‐
>    ple in EXAMPLE CRON FILE below).
> ```